# Rails Devise Token Auth authentification without using email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to use devise_token_auth gem with API app on Rails 5.0.2.
I installed gem typically as mentioned on https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth, so added to Gemfile, bundled and installed on User model. The problem is that, I don't want to use authentification (registration and login) with email. I just want to use telephone number instead (of course POST including with password and password_confirmation).

I added column :telephone_number, which will be unique to users table. And procced required steps to achieve this. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address

So this is what it looks like in code.

devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|
   ...
   config.authentication_keys = [ :telephone_number ]
   config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :telephone_number ]
   config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :telephone_number ]
   ...
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules.
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, :authentication_keys => [:telephone_number]
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

  def email_required?
    false
  end
  def email_changed?
    false
  end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:telephone_number, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
  end
end
```

Server is starting properly, no exception is given. But when I test registration with RESTfull services `POST on /auth` it gives me validation error, that email can't be blank.

```
{"status":"error","data":{"id":null,"provider":"email","uid":"",
"name":null,"nickname":null,"image":null,"email":null,
"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"telephone_number":"0123456789"},
"errors":{"email":["can't be blank","is not an email"],
"full_messages":["Email can't be blank","Email is not an email"]}}
```

EDIT:

Log from Puma

```
    Started POST "/auth?=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-24 15:17:13 +0200
    Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#create as */*
      Parameters: {"telephone_number"=>"0123456789", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
      "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "registration"=>{"telephone_number"=>"0123456789", 
      "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
    Unpermitted parameter: registration
    Unpermitted parameter: registration
    Unpermitted parameter: registration
       (0.3ms)  BEGIN
      SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("encrypted_password", "tokens", "created_at", 
     "updated_at", "telephone_number") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  
    [["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$PgCIPAGA1VH1erHvJX5Sg.f4IPmSyfSoVM3EVbKtHkbgeUvEGL5NG"], 
    ["tokens", "{}"], ["created_at", 2017-04-24 13:17:13 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-04-24 13:17:13 UTC], 
    ["telephone_number", "0123456789"]]
       (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
    Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 139ms (Views: 10.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

Reply on POST /auth

```
{"status":"error","data":{"id":null,"provider":"email","uid":"",
 "name":null,"nickname":null,"image":null,"email":null,
 "created_at":"2017-04-24T13:17:13.904Z","updated_at":"2017-04-24T13:17:13.904Z",
 "telephone_number":"0123456789"},"errors":["An account already exists for ''"]}
```

It is checking and validating email, which currently is "", so no account could be registered through.

Is there any config property I should add, or override some method ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you do:  'config.default_callbacks = false' in your devise_token_auth.rb initializer? Just for fun :)

Comment: Looks like it could help. I am now able to sign up new account and even sign in and obtain token etc..., but I am not able to register another number. Probably it is checking that email with value '' is reserved.

Comment: Read about the default_callback it has to do with validations in omniauth controller if set to true. I had an issue with double validations because of this. Check what you have in UID on the created account and if it is used to check uniqueness.

Comment: I still dont come up with overriding email validating. When registering new user, it comes with error - An account already exists for ' ', have you any ideas ?

Comment: Please try to register and post here the serve log of that call. Thanks.

Comment: @Anton Log added, did you mind some another log ?

Comment: First of all check out your params. You are posting same data in side nested hash. One of them is redundant. I bet the error comes from 'uid' attributes that devise uses. You need to sync the uid value with the value of your authentication_key (telephone_number). Try to add before_save and before create to user model and copy the value of telephone_number to uid.

Comment: Read about provider attribute.. may be you'll need to change it from email to the telephone.

Comment: Where you able to solve this?